# Matrix Values to Probabilities with Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have a Non Negative Matrix Factorization algorithm and I'm calculating the A-hat matrix from it.
Rows of the matrix are customers, columns are my products and values are the occurrences of product views.

Fitting the data to the model and I calculate the R matrix as follow.

```
model = NMF( n_components=100 )
W  = model.fit_transform( input_matrix )
H = model.components_
R = np.dot( W, H )
```

Then I want to calculate the probabilities to this matrix. Currently I can calculate them by normalizing the matrix with the following code

```
row_sums= R.sum(axis=1)
probabilities= R / row_sums[:, np.newaxis]
```

But its not 100% correct way to calculate the probabilities. The correct way is to run a logistic regression algorithm to generate them.

How to do that?

Comment: Probability of which event? What do we need the NNMF for?

Comment: Probability of a customer to purchase a product.